# Docker Cloud autotest doesn't exit after running tests

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-cloud

I'm trying to automatically test PRs to [my project](https://github.com/iquabius/olimat) using Docker Cloud. I've set up a build rule as follows:

[image: Docker Cloud build rule for autotest]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8.4.0-alpine

ENV NODE_ENV=production

WORKDIR /olimat/api

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --quiet

COPY ./public ./public
COPY ./config ./config
COPY ./src ./src

CMD npm start
```

Dockerfile.dev:

```
FROM node:8.4.0-alpine

WORKDIR /olimat/api

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --quiet

COPY ./public ./public
COPY ./config ./config

COPY ./src ./src

COPY ./db ./db
```

docker-compose.test.yml:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  sut:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    command: npm test
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: test
  api:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dev123
    image: postgres:9.6.4-alpine
```

Running the tests locally, with

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.test.yml run sut
```

Everything works fine:

[image: Testing locally]

On Docker Cloud, the tests run, but it seems to never return the exit code:

[image: Docker Cloud Autotest takes forever]

I've canceled after 1 hour and 46 minutes here. What's happening? How can I make the **sut** service container exit after the tests are run?

The complete build log:

```
Building in Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.253.112' to the list of known hosts.
Reset branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Pulling cache layers for index.docker.io/unemat/olimat-backend:latest...
Done!
KernelVersion: 4.4.0-93-generic
Arch: amd64
BuildTime: 2017-08-17T22:50:04.828747906+00:00
ApiVersion: 1.30
Version: 17.06.1-ce
MinAPIVersion: 1.12
GitCommit: 874a737
Os: linux
GoVersion: go1.8.3
Starting build of index.docker.io/unemat/olimat-backend:latest...
Step 1/9 : FROM node:8.4.0-alpine
---> 016382f39a51
Step 2/9 : ENV NODE_ENV production
---> Running in b0aa12f6d329
---> 8c0420481faa
Removing intermediate container b0aa12f6d329
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /olimat/api
---> 669997c76951
Removing intermediate container b9344977ce13
Step 4/9 : COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
---> 562fb1b9d9db
Removing intermediate container 3778fb63cd12
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install --quiet
---> Running in 459a90d4ce4f
> uws@0.14.5 install /olimat/api/node_modules/uws
> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0
added 261 packages in 19.34s
---> a22bd7c951bd
Removing intermediate container 459a90d4ce4f
Step 6/9 : COPY ./public ./public
---> 3555f3f71011
Removing intermediate container f6343f447c14
Step 7/9 : COPY ./config ./config
---> ffebbe0eae44
Removing intermediate container 1b6a25d1b044
Step 8/9 : COPY ./src ./src
---> ae66609e0177
Removing intermediate container a139a0a67b34
Step 9/9 : CMD npm start
---> Running in b1bc735877c5
---> fba69367a862
Removing intermediate container b1bc735877c5
Successfully built fba69367a862
Successfully tagged unemat/olimat-backend:latest
Starting Test in docker-compose.test.yml...
db uses an image, skipping
Building api
Step 1/9 : FROM node:8.4.0-alpine
---> 016382f39a51
Step 2/9 : ENV NODE_ENV production
---> Using cache
---> 8c0420481faa
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /olimat/api
---> Using cache
---> 669997c76951
Step 4/9 : COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
---> Using cache
---> 562fb1b9d9db
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install --quiet
---> Using cache
---> a22bd7c951bd
Step 6/9 : COPY ./public ./public
---> Using cache
---> 3555f3f71011
Step 7/9 : COPY ./config ./config
---> Using cache
---> ffebbe0eae44
Step 8/9 : COPY ./src ./src
---> Using cache
---> ae66609e0177
Step 9/9 : CMD npm start
---> Using cache
---> fba69367a862
Successfully built fba69367a862
Successfully tagged bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_api:latest
Building sut
Step 1/9 : FROM node:8.4.0-alpine
---> 016382f39a51
Step 2/9 : MAINTAINER Josias Iquabius 
---> Running in ed1306bea19a
---> 5956fb44e0cc
Removing intermediate container ed1306bea19a
Step 3/9 : WORKDIR /olimat/api
---> be7fd8615cd4
Removing intermediate container 2bde5cfe6bdd
Step 4/9 : COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
---> b68a99364f80
Removing intermediate container d0f4715b4774
Step 5/9 : RUN npm install --quiet
---> Running in f9f053df7774
> uws@0.14.5 install /olimat/api/node_modules/uws
> node-gyp rebuild > build_log.txt 2>&1 || exit 0
added 666 packages in 32.983s
---> 8f2ace5a6f9e
Removing intermediate container f9f053df7774
Step 6/9 : COPY ./public ./public
---> 0cac78c670e2
Removing intermediate container ab0f50cbc747
Step 7/9 : COPY ./config ./config
---> ce57c484d544
Removing intermediate container 126828beed7d
Step 8/9 : COPY ./src ./src
---> 7cd682b0f4d9
Removing intermediate container 819d441c2307
Step 9/9 : COPY ./db ./db
---> 244561b4bc52
Removing intermediate container 1a80d8f935b4
Successfully built 244561b4bc52
Successfully tagged bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_sut:latest
Creating network "bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_default" with the default driver
Pulling db (postgres:9.6.4-alpine)...
9.6.4-alpine: Pulling from library/postgres
Digest: sha256:5fd73de311d304caeb4f907d4f559d322805abc622e4baf5788c6a079ee5224e
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:9.6.4-alpine
Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_db_1 ...
Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_db_1
Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_db_1 ... done Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_api_1 ...
Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_api_1
Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_api_1 ... done Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_sut_1 ...
Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_sut_1
Creating bs3klcfwuijavr4uf4daf28_sut_1 ... done
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.4.0
npm info lifecycle olimat-backend@0.0.1~pretest: olimat-backend@0.0.1
npm info lifecycle olimat-backend@0.0.1~test: olimat-backend@0.0.1
> olimat-backend@0.0.1 test /olimat/api
> jest
PASS src/services/questions/questions.test.js
● Console
console.log src/models/questions.model.js:10
questions table does not exists!
info: after: questions - Method: find
PASS src/app.test.js
Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
Tests: 5 passed, 5 total
Snapshots: 0 total
Time: 6.505s
Ran all test suites.
Build canceled.
ERROR: Build failed with exit code 3
Build in 'master:/api' (4eeca024) canceled after 1:46:31
```

Comment: I've faced the same issue many times without finding a reliable solution. Seems that the [autobuild feature isn't stable](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-cloud-build-failing-without-log/21865/5). Have you tried building on your nodes?

Comment: Are you sure the node process has no issues? I have sometimes seen that a unintentional callback or deferred could keep Node running in certain situations.

Comment: @lifeisfoo I don't have a cloud provider, but I think I could try AWS free tier for this!? I may end up using TravisCI for testing, it seems to be straightforward.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't think so. Shouldn't that occur locally as well!? I've updated the question with the complete build log.

Comment: Yes, give it a try. But don't forget to write about your problem in the docker forum.